# Adding numbers to a listview

Tags: c++, c, winapi, listview

I'm trying to add show my structure in a listview. `TCHAR` fields displays normally, but for numbers it shows wrong empty rectangles or chinese symbols. Debugger shows correct string after conversion.
Here is my structure:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned phone_number, house, appartment;
    TCHAR Name[30], Street[15], date[11];
} PHONE_DATA;
```

I'm initializing items and subitems values with`LVN_GETDISPINFO` callback.

```
TCHAR wStr[16];
//other code

switch (((LPNMHDR) lParam)->code)
{
case LVN_GETDISPINFO:

    plvdi = (NMLVDISPINFO*)lParam;
    entry = Get(&list, plvdi->item.iItem);

    switch (plvdi->item.iSubItem)
    {
    case 0:
        plvdi->item.pszText = entry->data.Name;
        break;
    case 1:     
        _itow(entry->data.phone_number, wStr, 10);
        plvdi->item.pszText = wStr;
        break;
    case 2:
        plvdi->item.pszText = entry->data.Street;
        break;
    case 3:
        _itow(entry->data.house, wStr, 10);
        plvdi->item.pszText = wStr;
        break;
    case 4:
        _itow(entry->data.appartment, wStr, 10);
        plvdi->item.pszText = wStr;
        break;
    case 5:
        plvdi->item.pszText = entry->data.date;
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    break;
}
```

And how it looks in my listview:
[image: Listview]

Same conversion I'm using for my edit form, in textboxes it displays correctly.

Comment: Each time you call _itow you are using the same buffer - wStr.  So it is getting overwritten.  It is possible that you are even over-writing it elsewhere as well.

Comment: but debugger displays correct string. I tried to flush buffer before use it, nothing has changed.

Comment: Is `TCHAR wStr[16];` a global variable or is it defined within the function handling `WM_NOTIFY`? If the latter, it's not valid once that function returns.

Comment: @JonathanPotter THANK YOU! wStr variable was defined within WM_NOTIFY handle, now it works perfectly! Please, post an answer so I can confirm it.

Comment: No problem, have done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `TCHAR wStr[16];` is defined within the function handling `WM_NOTIFY` then it won't be valid when the function returns. Change that to a global variable or make it `static` and it will fix the problem.

Note that when you get the `LVN_GETDISPINFO` notification the control provides you a buffer you can use, so you could change your code to do this:

```
case 4:
    _itow_s(entry->data.appartment, plvdi->item.pszText, plvdi->item.cchTextMax, 10);
    break;
```